# Show that recursive sequence is decreasing

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

[image]

I'm required to show that the above series is decreasing. However, I encounter a problem when I realize that in the inductive step, I have  a term for a(n) in both the numerator and denominator, which makes it difficult to show that a(n+1) > a(n+2). Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you plotted the graph of $g(x) = x/2  + 1/x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to show that $a_{n+1}<a_n$ for all $n\geq1$. Writing this out yields
$$\frac{a_n}{2}+\frac{1}{a_n}<a_n,$$
and subtracting $\frac{a_n}{2}$ from both sides leaves us with
$$\frac{1}{a_n}<\frac{a_n}{2}.$$
This is equivalent to $a_n^2>2$. Can you prove this by induction?

Comment: In the inductive step, I get that (a(k+1))^2 > 3/2 + (1/a(k))^2. I'm struggling to get the 2 term. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: make the inductive hypothesis be: if $a_n > \sqrt{2}$ then $a_{n+1} > \sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 0):

If
$a_{n+1}
=\dfrac{a_n}{2}+\dfrac1{a_n}
$
then
$a_{n+1}-a_n
=-\dfrac{a_n}{2}+\dfrac1{a_n}
=\dfrac{-a_n^2+2}{2a_n}
$.

If
$a_n > \sqrt{2}$
then
$a_{n+1} < a_n$.

Also,
$a_{n+1}^2
=\dfrac{a_n^2}{4}+1+\dfrac1{a_n^2}
$
so
$a_{n+1}^2-2
=\dfrac{a_n^2}{4}-1+\dfrac1{a_n^2}
=(\dfrac{a_n}{2}-\dfrac1{a_n})^2
=(\dfrac{a_n^2-2}{2a_n})^2
$
so that
$a_{n+1} > \sqrt{2}$.

Therefore
if $a_n > \sqrt{2}$
then
$\sqrt{2} < a_{m+1} < a_m
$
for
$m \ge n$.

Therefore,
for any initial
$a_1 > 0$,
for all $n \ge 2$
we have
$\sqrt{2} < a_{n+1}
\lt a_n$
so
$a_n \to^+ \sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score -2):

Here’s a hint. Consider when the sequence would not decrease, namely where it would stay constant. To do this, solve:

$$x=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{x}$$
$$x^2=2 \implies x=\{-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}\}$$

Since this sequence is always positive, the positive solution seems most relevant. As matter of fact, whenever $ a_n> \sqrt{2}$, $a_{n+1}$ decreases. I’ll leave it to you to rigorously prove the above claim, and show that $x>\sqrt{2} \implies \frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{x}>\sqrt{2}$

Comment: But that's not true, it could for instance increase.

Comment: The idea is that the solutions of this, along with discontinuities are analogous to critical points, and in between “critical points” you cannot switch from increasing to decreasing. Since $\sqrt{2}$ is the largest “critical point” then all $x$ greater than it will all behave the same, and by observer group for one value that they decrease, it’s true for all values greater than root two.

Comment: nevertheless it was poorly communicated, but hopefully the method behind it is of some use.

Comment: I can't grok it. Suppose that indeed, $x_0 = x_0/2 + 1/x_0$. Suppose that indeed, $x > \sqrt{2}$ and that we proved that $x/2 + 1/x > \sqrt{2}$. How does it prove anything? We just know that the sequence is bounded from below. We still don't know anything about the monotonicity of the sequence.

Comment: think of $a_{n+1}-a_n$ as a function. a function cannot go from being negative to positive without in between either having a zero or a discontinuity. there are no zeros nor discontinuities past $\sqrt{2}$, and one can observe that this difference is negative for one value past this point, therefore it must hold for all values past this point.